# Give a user the ability to add App Background capabilities in iOS

Tags: ios, info.plist

I have an iOS app that needs to use background audio, but I would like the user to have control of the audio in the background. Can the info.plist capabilities be changed programmatically? to add audio background modes only when a user chooses it in the application settings?

Best,

F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can’t programmatically change the contents of info.plist, the way I’d go about this would be:

- Declare your app plays audible content while in the background.
- If the user has opted-in to background audio in your app settings, set an appropriate Audio Session Category, *e.g.* [`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback). Otherwise play it using the default [`AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategorysoloambient.).

**Note**: The app needs to have an active Audio Session before it goes to background.

For further info, also have a look at [technical Q&A 1668](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1668/_index.html).